# Arranging hundreds of pictures on a PowerPoint slide

Tags: adobe-photoshop, microsoft-powerpoint

every quarter I have to take roughly 100-200 thumbnails of slightly varying size and arrange them on a PowerPoint slide. Each image is scalable of another but some may be 100x400 while others are 200x800. Is there anyway to have PowerPoint or Photoshop automatically align these images for me in one slide or image?

Thank you

Comment: 100-200 images on a single slide?  Or on a series of slides, each with some smaller number of images?  All images the same size, ie, in a grid pattern of some sort?  PowerPoint offers no way of doing this directly, but could be automated via VBA or some other language to do the job, at least in Windows PPT and probably Mac PPT 2011.  Can't speak for Mac 2016, but it'd be more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :) Ended up using Photoshop and the Contact Sheet feature: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/contact-sheet-pdf-presentation-cs6.html

Answer (score 2):

You could always use Google Picasa and create a 'picture collage'. This simply looks at any number of images in a folder - then you can create a 'grid' collage at whatever size you want. Save it as an image and then import into Powerpoint. I do this a lot and takes approx 5 minutes (once you have the images that is)

[image]

Comment: "What is this?  A PowerPoint for ants?!"

Answer (score 1):

I see you have you have already a solution. However, I would appreciate if you would take a look at SlideMight, a data fusion tool for PowerPoint, comparable to mail merge. SlideMight supports iterations for slides and table rows, nested iterations, normal images and images in tables.

See [www.slidemight.com](http://www.slidemight.com)

There is a free trial version available for download. Could you give me some feedback about how well SlideMight would have served you in the hypothetical case that you would not have Photoshop with the Contact Sheet feature?

**Disclaimer**: I am the developer and vendor of SlideMight.